# Sales Order SOLines Conditionally Disabled tranDesc being overridden

Tags: acumatica

I have custom code on the Sales Order form that prevents editing SOLine descriptions unless it's a specific SOLine Code. I see that my custom code is being reached, but it seems that something else is overriding my logic, enabling editing on the field after I disable it. I was wondering if there are pre-defined automations that might be doing this for the Sales Order screen, or if there is some other place I should be looking to prevent this behavior.

//I had debug code that validated that RowSelected and SetEnabled were begin called

public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension
  {

```
#region Event Handlers    

protected void SOLine_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (SOLine)e.Row;

  if(row != null && row.InventoryID.HasValue) {
    //Only allow editing of parts description if the partno is 'NOTE'
    InventoryItem inventoryItem = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(this.Base, row.InventoryID);
    if(inventoryItem.InventoryCD == "NOTE") {   
      PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLine.tranDesc>(cache, row, true); 
    } else {
      PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLine.tranDesc>(cache, row, false); 
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: without your code, how can we check?

Comment: it is best to include the code you are using on the sales order page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your **RowSelected** handler will make no effect on the Line Description column because of how automation steps are configured for the Sales Orders screen:

[image]

In order to keep Line Description open for editing, you should change a number of Automation Steps disabling the entire Document Details grid on Sales Orders and subscribe to **RowSelected** handler for the **SOOrder** DAC to allow editing on the cache level for the **SOOrder** and **SOLine** DACs. Below are the changes required to enable Line Description for ***completed*** sales orders (if necessary, similar changes should be made to other Automation steps defined for the Sales Orders screen):

1. Subscribe to **SOOrder_RowSelected** handler to allow editing on the cache level for the **SOOrder** and **SOLine** DACs:

   ```
   public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
   {
       public void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
       {
           SOOrder order = e.Row as SOOrder;
           if (order != null && order.Status == SOOrderStatus.Completed)
           {
               sender.AllowUpdate = true;
               Base.Transactions.Cache.AllowUpdate = true;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Modify Sales Orders' **SO Completed** automation step to open Line Description for editing. In addition to enabled Line Description, it's necessary to enable at least one of the SOOrder fields, otherwise the **Save** button will never become enabled for completed sales orders:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Ruslan. Very thorough and helpful.